# Show that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=a \ \text{and} \ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=b$ then $b=0$

Tags: limits, functions

Consider: $$f:[c,\infty] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

Show that if:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=a \ \text{and} \ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=b$$

Then: $$b=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $f$ is $C^1$.

**Hint:** Assume that $\lim f' = b >0$. Then $f'(x)\ge \frac b2>0$ for $x$ large enough. Now what is the limit of $f(x) = f(c) + \displaystyle\int_{c}^{x} f'(x) dx$?